# axvspan in subplot not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I try to color in different subplots.

My code:

```
f, (ax) = plt.subplots(1, 7 , sharey=True, figsize=(14,2))
color=['g','c','m','y','g','c','m']
for k in range(7):
    ax[k].axvspan(0,100,facecolor=color[k], alpha = 0.3)
    ax[k].plot(data[k]['x'], data[k]['y'], color=color[k])
    ax[k].set_xscale('log')
```

It does the plot, but not the coloring, though no error is raised. When I don't set_xscale('log'), then it works. 
Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma on the first line, and fix your identing.

Then make sure you set the log scale before making the axvspan.

```
f, (ax) = plt.subplots(1, 7 , sharey=True, figsize=(14,2))
color=['g','c','m','y','g','c','m']
for k in range(7):
    ax[k].set_xscale('log')
    ax[k].axvspan(0,100,facecolor=color[k], alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

If you're looking for a way to color the background, you should use `ax[k].set_axis_bgcolor(color[k])` instead.

Also, you might be better off using `axhspan` instead, since it will use axis (relative) units for x.

```
ax[k].set_ylim(0,1)
ax[k].set_xscale('log')
ax[k].axhspan(0,1,facecolor=color[k], alpha = 0.3)
```

Comment: the coma and the wrong indent were just sloppiness while copying the code, but I've found the possible error and edited the question